# Python web scraping(request.get) can't get target web page

Tags: python, get, request

I am using Python `requests.get` to **scrape** a website. It worked fine yesterday, but issues happened today.
I can't get `requests.text` as before. Now, `requests` returns `This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly. Please allow up to 5 seconds`.

To solve this problem, I tried to set `time.sleep()` function inside `requests.get`. But it didn't work and I still get the allow up to 5 seconds response as before.

Here's my code below:

```
def web_scraping_corporationwiki(df):
    # Scrape website
    df_scrape = df.reset_index()
    for i in df_scrape.index:
        name = df_scrape.loc[i, 'Name']
        state =  df_scrape.loc[i, 'State']
        origin_row = df_scrape.loc[i]
        url = 'https://www.corporationwiki.com/search/withfacets?term='+ name +'&stateFacet='+ state
        for page_num in range(8):
            req = requests.get(url, time.sleep(50), params= dict(query="wiki", page = page_num),timeout = 100A)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
            page = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'list-group-item')
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as an image! This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks. Just updated.

Comment: FYI It’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap